# Eclipse editor/build losing access to imported javax classes

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I fixed my problem but I don't know how/why this fixed it so I am looking for an explanation.

I opened my project yesterday and I could no longer build due to the fact that the java and jsp imports could no longer see javax.* classes.  I had another project that worked fine but could find no differences in their build paths.

After reading several threads on build path, etc. and not finding any problems in the configuration file I simply retyped the import in one of the source files, eclipse was able to lookup class tree as I typed in the editor, and once one of the imports was retyped the project would now build.

I would like to understand what in the Eclipse project configuration was hit and why this happened and how this method I used actually resolved the problem.

Comment: Hard to say. If the problem no longer exists, it'll be difficult to find the underlying issue, since you can no longer find/supply any additional evidence. Editing a file will cause Eclipse to recompile it, and sometimes that can resolve issues with stale compiled code lying around. But again, impossible to say for certain since you can no longer reproduce it.